# Spss 24 (which is java) freezing on output save after long idle time in Win 10 1703

Tags: java, debugging, windows-10, freeze, spss

The title says it all.  I'm trying to troubleshoot Spss freezing up on trying to open an output save dialog box after an hour idle time (the box never appears).  It's a java program.  Support can't reproduce it.  What solid evidence can I give them?  Task manager in Windows 10 says it's still running, but the interface is completely frozen.

Comment: Is your output extremely large ? what do you have in it? I never worked in SPSS 24, but what do you mean by "SPSS 24, which is Java" ?

Comment: The output is small.  I'm just using an example.  Spss is an exe, but it's written in java.

Answer (score 0):

We have the exact same issue, speaking with IBM SPSS support they pointed to a possible correlation with Edge browsers crashes in some extended logging we did with SPSS.

Comment: How do you do extended logging?  Spss is two processes, and I believe if they get slightly out of sync communicating on a fast computer, bad things happen.

Comment: enable trace.properties. This file is on C:\Program Files\IBM\SPSS\Statistics\25\utility folder. copy it to C:\Program Files\IBM\SPSS\Statistics\25\ instead.

If no path is defined the trace log the trace log will be written to users home folder

(TRACE_FILE_PATH_NAME = %h/statistics_client_trace_file%u.log)

To tell you the truth wasn't a whole lot of useful info in the trace log. I'm still going back and fourth with SPSS support. If you make headway please contact me rfh23@humboldt.edu I'll post anything I find if I get a breakthrough.